# php page working fine on PC but not on cellphone

Tags: php, html, pdf

On cellphone, it tried to download the php file instead of rendering it. On a Huawei it downloads it as myfile.php.hmtl

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "***";
$password = "";
$dbname = "***************";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
    $sql = "SELECT *  from test ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);      
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    echo $row["im"];

?>
```

Tried reading a BLOB and displaying as pdf. Works on PC but on cellphone it tries to download the page instead of displaying it.

[error msg]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLooQ.png

[on pc it looks like this (pdf loads)] [1]:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fAv5.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I added 2 pics to the problems.

Comment: Android or iPhone? The mobile browser is being picky. You could pipe the pdf url through google with their inline display js... `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url={your_pdf_url_here}` ... Might not be a viable solution though in a production setting.

Comment: Android tested so far, the pdf is from a database (BLOB)